# XML Help in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-parsing

We receive a full block of XML with various segments on it.

Need help in separating XML segments into separate XML chunks into local xml variables.

The local xml variable, holding the separated XML segments, will be passed on parameter to another stored procedure.

For eg:

```
Declare @Message xml
set @Message  = 
'<Message>
    <Procedure>sp_testProc</Procedure>
    <Customer>
       <row>
          <CustID>111</CustID>
          <CustName>TestName2</CustName>
       </row> 
       <row>
          <CustID>222</CustID>
          <CustName>TestName2</CustName>
       </row> 
    </Customer>
    <Product>
       <ProdCode>AA</ProdCode>
       <ProdName>TestProdAA</ProdName>
    </Product>
 </Message>'

 select @Message 

 Declare @Proc xml
 Declare @Customer XML
 Declare @Product xml

 ----Need query help to extract as below, from @Message.
 set @Proc = '<Procedure>sp_testProc</Procedure>'

 set @Customer = 
     '<Customer>
         <row>
           <CustID>111</CustID>
           <CustName>TestName2</CustName>
         </row> 
         <row>
            <CustID>222</CustID>
            <CustName>TestName2</CustName>
         </row> 
       </Customer>'
   set @Product =
       '<Product>
            <ProdCode>AA</ProdCode>
            <ProdName>TestProdAA</ProdName>
       </Product>'
```

Comment: Hi, is this still open? Do you need further help? If this issue is solved, it would be kind to tick the acceptance check below the vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. As you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is called `.query()`

With these lines you'll get the portions separated:

```
Declare @Message xml
set @Message  = 
'<Message>
    <Procedure>sp_testProc</Procedure>
    <Customer>
       <row>
          <CustID>111</CustID>
          <CustName>TestName2</CustName>
       </row> 
       <row>
          <CustID>222</CustID>
          <CustName>TestName2</CustName>
       </row> 
    </Customer>
    <Product>
       <ProdCode>AA</ProdCode>
       <ProdName>TestProdAA</ProdName>
    </Product>
 </Message>';

 SELECT @Message.query('/Message/Procedure') AS TheProc
       ,@Message.query('/Message/Customer') AS TheCust
       ,@Message.query('/Message/Product') AS TheProd
```

### UPDATE

And this is the code to fill three variables at once

```
 Declare @Proc xml
 Declare @Customer XML
 Declare @Product xml

     SELECT @Proc=@Message.query('/Message/Procedure')
           ,@Customer=@Message.query('/Message/Customer') 
           ,@Product=@Message.query('/Message/Product');

SELECT @Proc;
SELECT @Customer;
SELECT @Product
```